# Reference Items in Generated List for Multiple Record Selection and Iterate

Tags: arcpy, data, cursor, iterator

I'm new to Python and am having trouble with a list of all things.  The data I am currently working with consists of multiple road segments (contained in 'STREETNAME' field) each of which has a measured length ('Shape_Length'), for every named road.  I am trying to sum the 'Shape_Length' values for each road and populate a new field, 'Total_Length', with the calculated values.

To do so, I have created a list of unique values for the 'STREETNAME' field and thought I could loop through the list selecting all records whose 'STREETNAME' value matched a list value (so, for example, select all records whose 'STREETNAME' = "Bob Rd", conduct calculations for those records, unselect; select all records whose 'STREETNAME' = "Bobby Rd', etc).  Problem is I haven't figured out how to pull values from the list to run the selection tool or if that is possible to begin with.  The code thus far is below.  The program returns an error stating "'module' object has no attribute 'SelectLayerbyAttribute_management'".

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\NGraderNetwork"

#Define feature classes and fields

inFC = env.workspace + "\\Source.gdb\\NGraderADT_Materials"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFC, "tempLayer")
outFC = env.workspace + "\\Source.gdb\\NGraderADT_Rock"

Field1 = 'STREETNAME'
Field2 = 'Shape_Length'
Field3 = 'Total_Length'

print "defined"

#Create list of all roads in North District

RoadList = []

Roads = arcpy.SearchCursor(inFC)
for row in Roads:
    if row.getValue(Field1) not in RoadList:
        RoadList.append(row.getValue(Field1))
del row, Roads
print "created roadlist"

#Select records in feature class by roads in RoadList

while RoadList[0:]
query =  "STREETNAME =" + str(RoadList[0:])
arcpy.SelectLayerbyAttributes_management("tempLayer","NEW_SELECTION", query)
Selection = arcpy.SearchCursor(inFC)
for row in Selection:
    Length = row.getValue(Field2)
    print Length
    RoadLength = sum(Length)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management("tempLayer", Field3, RoadLength)
    print Field3
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("tempLayer", outFC)
arcpy.SelectbyAttributes_management(inFC, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

del RoadList
arcpy.Delete_management("tempLayer")

print "Finished"
```

Comment: Your code has `arcpy.SelectLayerbyAttributes_management`, when it should be `arcpy.SelectLayerbyAttribute_management` (`attributes`/`attribute`).

Comment: Are you interested in having the shape length in miles, kilometers or another human readable measure?

Comment: Richard - Thanks for that.  What an silly mistake to not have caught myself.

Comment: Pura - I already know that the shape_length is in meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a da cursor to make your code 10 times faster.  Replace the list with a dictionary where the keys are the streetnames and the value is the sum of all lengths.  Then you can write it all back in a single pass of an update cursor.  At the same time you can get the OID list and do a single SelectLayerbyAttribute to Copy all the features at once to the outFC.  This code will run between 20 and 100 times faster.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\NGraderNetwork"

#Define feature classes and fields

inFC = env.workspace + "\\Source.gdb\\NGraderADT_Materials"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inFC, "tempLayer")
outFC = env.workspace + "\\Source.gdb\\NGraderADT_Rock"

fields = ['STREETNAME', 'Shape_Length']
print "defined"

#Create Dict of all roads in North District

RoadDict = {}

with arcpy.da.searchCursor(inFC, fields) as Roads:
    for row in Roads:
        Road = row[0]
        if not Road in RoadDict:
            RoadDict[Road] = row[1]
        else:
            RoadDict[Road] += row[1]
print "created RoadDict"

#Update all matching roads
fields = ['STREETNAME', 'Shape_Total', "OID@"]
OIDList = []
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inFC, fields) as updateRows:  
    for updateRow in updateRows:  
        # store the Join value of the row being updated in a Road variable  
        Road = updateRow[0]  
        # verify that the Road is in the Dictionary  
        if Road in RoadDict:  
            updateRow[1] = RoadDict[Road]
            updateRows.updateRow(updateRow)
            OIDList.append(row[2])


arcpy.SelectLayerbyAttribute("tempLayer", "OBJECTID IN ({0})".format(",".join(OIDList)))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("tempLayer", outFC)
del RoadDict
```

Comment: Richard - I believe the for loop section when adding the roads needs to be indented?

Comment: Fixed the indentation.

Comment: I haven't heard of a "dictionary" before.  How exactly do these differ from a standard list?  It looks like it's able to track the number of entries and information for a single road name?

Comment: A dictionary is data collection that stores a key:value pair, where the key is used to look up the related value.  The key is equivalent to a list index, so instead of using a meaningless number as an index you can use a meaningful name or value to look up the related value.  Dictionaries use a heap and the look up time of any key value will not slow down no matter how big they grow.  The first time I encounter a Road Name I add it and its length to the dictionary, but every other time I encounter that name I sum the stored length with the current length I am reading to get a total by the end.

Comment: The dictionary contains all the road names paired with all of their total lengths by the time the first search cursor completes its loop.  The update cursor just writes it back by looking up the road name of the record currently being updated from the dictionary to get its total length.  The value in the dictionary can be a string, a number, a tuple, a list, another dictionary, etc.  So the look up of a dictionary can be very powerful.

Comment: It is called a "Dictionary", because a real world dictionary is optimized to let you quickly look up a word or phrase (a key value) to access its related description, translation, definition, pronunciation, etc. (the related value).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't iterating over `RoadList`: you're essentially doing this each time:

```
>>> "OID = " + str([1,2,3,4])
'OID = [1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

To change this, you could use a for loop instead:

```
for road in RoadList:
  query = "STREETNAME = '{}'".format(road)
```

As an alternative approach, there is a GP tool that does this for you very simply: [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm). From this table, you can either use [Add Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) and Calculate field or use cursors to loop over the table and update `inFC`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Paul.  What does the query line "state" in lamens terms?

Comment: @ZakHaverly, it's just an alternative way to insert values into strings. I find it simpler than the equivalent `"STREETNAME = '" + str(road) + "'"`